# Creating multiple copies of a file while changing a specific number everytime

Tags: python, bash, shell

I have a specific script that I need to duplicate x amount of times (100 times) but I need a specific number in the file to change (increase by one) each time the file is duplicated.

Example:

```
vina=/home/x/xxx/bin/vina
path=/home/x/xxx/Virtual_Screening

# Execute the job code

for f in $path/*.pdbqt;do
    $vina --config $path/BatchConfig.txt --receptor $path/5u1w_receptor.pdbqt --batch $path/ligands/*.pdbqt --dir $path/outputs/001
done
```

I would want the script to be changed to:

```
vina=/home/x/xxx/bin/vina
path=/home/x/xxx/Virtual_Screening

# Execute the job code

for f in $path/*.pdbqt;do
    $vina --config $path/BatchConfig.txt --receptor $path/5u1w_receptor.pdbqt --batch $path/ligands/*.pdbqt --dir $path/outputs/002
done
```

For more context, I need the script to be duplicated 100 times instead of accessing the 100 folders using * due to disk space limitations.

The particular section of the script that needs editing is the three digit number after '--dir' which needs to increase by 1 each time the file script is copied 001 --> 002 ... --> 010 ... --> 100

I'm quite new to shell scripting and python scripting so any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It's possible to make 100 files like this, but it's likely a terrible way to solve your problem. You should describe the problem you're actually trying to solve.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it more clear but sadly this is the only way to solve my problem.

Comment: Why is this tagged with `python` please? It looks like a `bash` script to me.

Comment: I was told that both bash and python scripts could perform the task so I have tagged both languages

Comment: So you want to duplicate and modify the scrip ? can't you just put your for f loof inside another loop or vice-versa ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by duplicating you mean copying to a new file and changing 001

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {001..100}; do 
    cp script.sh "script_$i.sh" && sed -i "s/001$/$i/g" "script_$i.sh"
done

$ grep -o "outputs/..." *
script_001.sh:outputs/001
script_002.sh:outputs/002
script_003.sh:outputs/003
script_004.sh:outputs/004
...
```

Comment: I get the following error when attempting to run the script ' duplication_script.sh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `<' duplication_script.sh: line 6: done < <(printf '%s\n' {001..100}) '

Comment: I made a typo and it worked for the first number which is amazing. However, I have had to make an edit to the script and the number 001 appears twice, is there any way to change both occurrences in the script?

Comment: This worked perfectly, only edit I had to make was removing the dollar sign after 001 in the sed command. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Is that better ? :

```
for i in $(seq -f "%05g" 1 100);do
    for f in $path/*.pdbqt;do
        $vina --config $path/BatchConfig.txt --receptor $path/5u1w_receptor.pdbqt --batch $path/ligands/*.pdbqt --dir $path/outputs/$i
    done
done
```

Comment: This works but not exactly how I want it to. What I ideally want is a script that creates 100 copies of the script so I can run the script 100 times concurrently instead of running the vina software 100 times one after another which would increase computational time exponentially